# DOM injection with namespace

Tags: javascript

I know that extending DOM elements is a bad practice. But I was wondering if it's ok to inject methods to specific elements under namespace. Following example shows what I mean.

```
var element = document.getElementById('my-element');

var inject = function (element) { 
    var nameSpace = element.nameSpace = {};
    nameSpace.method1 = function () {
        //do something
    }
    nameSpace.method2 = function () {
        //do something
    }
}

inject(element);
```

Is this acceptable?

Comment: Why do you need this? You if want to associate functions and some data with DOM elements you could always just write a wrapper.

Comment: Potential name collision is actually _one_ of the reasons not to extend DOM element - but not the only one. Here's [more](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) on this topic.

Comment: Thanks for link. I have read that already, though. I'm asking this because this is really fast way to add additional methods and cross browser implementations (like cross browser getElementByClassName) to single element.

Comment: I think the time saved here will be spent on fixing bugs. After all, if you need shims for gEBCN and like, you definitely intend to extend DOM objects in IE8 as well - and that's, well, nasty.

Comment: I have written library based on this and everything is worked fine in IE6, IE7 and IE8. But could there be in future something like elements gets locked and you can't insert objects in them.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: No, that's not true. To associate data to DOM elements you always will need to set at least one property on them

Comment: @Bergi, that changes under the next version of JavaScript with [WeakMaps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that extending elements is what you're looking for, but look rather at it from the perspective of adding listeners to your code for those elements.

Where you put those handlers, however, is a good place for namespacing.

For example:

```
var myNS = {};
myNS.count = 0;
myNS.method1 = function(){
  var out = document.getElementById("out");
  out.innerHTML = "Clicked " + myNS.count++ + " times!";        
};

window.onload = function(){
    var elem = document.getElementById('my-element');
    elem.addEventListener('click',myNS.method1, false);
};​
```

(See this jsFiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/3CjEW/)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I think you kind of misunderstood me. Question is about namespace in element, not outside of element.

Comment: Well, the issue I can see with that approach, as outlined in your code above, is that it would only be per-instance ... in other words, only the one element would carry that method... and it would be very fragile, apt to break and cause a lot of re-coding if you needed to adjust your markup structures over time. If that element ever got disrupted, or was parsed by something that doesn't allow for non-strict handling of DOM elements, you've got broken code.

Comment: My bad. I tried to make code as simple as it can be. I edited it to be more like in my library. Idea is to be able to inject as many element as needed and that those elements carry all methods for then on.